# Scrollbar shown by default using Vuetify 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I am trying to use Vuetify (3.4.7) in my Vue 3 project, but for some reason, when I start the server, I am getting an empty scrollbar on the screen that I can not manage to make disappear.

Below, you can see a photo of the problem and my code:

Problem:
[empty scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Okd7P.png)

**main.js:**

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";

// Vuetify
import 'vuetify/styles'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'

import App from "./App.vue";


const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
  })

createApp(App).use(vuetify).mount("#app");
```

**App.vue:**

```
<template>
  <Navbar />
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Navbar,
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss"></style>
```

**Navbar.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div>teste</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Navbar-Component",
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong.  Your app is just a single div with the word "teste".  This is all you've written so this is all that you should expect to see.

Comment: Yes, that's why i don't understand why it shows a white bar at the right corner of the screen. I mean, i literally did nothing crazy, i just installed the Vuetify and put a div with "teste". But when i take off the code of vuetify, it stops to show this white bar.

Comment: I didn't initially understand what you mean by white bar.  I thought maybe you just meant white screen.  You mean the _scrollbar_?  I can't speak to the Vuetify team's decision for it, but you can **always** override the look of **anything** with your own CSS.  Here you just need `html { overflow-y: auto }`

Comment: You may also need the `!important` keyword.  I've added the information as an answer along with a link to an open Github issue I found with others encountering the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Vuetify team, for whatever reason, has by default included CSS that automatically displays the vertical scrollbar. This is an  [issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/16994) on their Github, now closed with explanation that they won't fix it.

To change this styling, you can apply your own CSS to override

```css
html { 
  overflow-y: auto !important 
}
```

This can be added to any global stylesheet in your project.